# How to display two legends of a fieldset in the same line?

Tags: html, css, user-interface

I have a fieldset titled "Input". I want to show that the fields in the fieldset are mandatory and hence trying to put a red star before them. The code below gives the star within the lines of fieldset, but puts the header "Input" inside the fieldset on a different line. How can I have them on the same line such that the title looks like "*Input" where the * is in red color?

```
<fieldset style="border: 2px solid; ">
    <legend style="color:#685645;font-weight:bold;font-size:1.1em">*</legend>
    <legend style="color:#696969;font-weight:bold;font-size:1.1em">Input</legend>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Use `display: inline;` for the legend elements...also, ditch the inline styles. Use classes and a `CSS` sheet. Even this small excerpt is messy.

Answer (score 1):

Like this

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/EeyMR/1/)**

**CSS**

```
   fieldset{
    float:left;
    width:300px;
  }
span{
    color:red;
}
```

**HTML**

```
 <fieldset style="border: 2px solid; ">
    <legend style="color:#685645;font-weight:bold;font-size:1.1em"><span>*</span>  Input</legend>

</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SgfkK/).

HTML

```
<fieldset style="border: 2px solid; ">
<legend>
    <span>*</span>
    Input
</legend>
</fieldset>
```

CSS

```
legend {
color:#696969;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:1.1em;
```

}

```
span {
color:red;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:1.1em;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to use `::before` instead, as in:

**HTML**

```
<legend class="mandatory">Input</legend>
```

**CSS**

```
.mandatory::before {
  content: "* ";
  color: red;
}
```

Then you've got a reusable class.